# Non constant expression as attribute argument in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to have a .csv file as an attribute argument, but initially using a relative path, like this:

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", datapath, "data#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("data.csv")]
```

In this case the string `datapath` must be a `const string`. But if I get the full path with

```
const string datapath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"data.csv";
```

This will not work because as I found out the expression assigned to a `const` in C# needs to be constant at compile time. I've also tried a `private readonly` instead of a `const` but the  compiler complains that the argument needs to be of type `const`. So how can I get this relative datapath as an argument?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 targeting .NET framework 4.0

Comment: You are asking how to pass in a relative path, but the code sample you use above with `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will give you a result that is an absolute path and not a relative path.

Comment: Ah true, wrong phrasing. I meant I want the absolute path as attribute while specifying only the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to derive your own DataSource class. For example:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyDataSource : DataSource
{
    public MyDataSource(string providerInvariantName, string fileName, string tableName, DataAccessMethod dataAccessMethod)
        : base(providerInvariantName, Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName). tableName, dataAccessMethod)
    {
    }
}
```

In this sample you would pass in an argument called `fileName` and before passing that onto the base constructor you would use `Path.Combine` to create an absolute path to the file. Then in place of the `DataSourceAttribute` you would use `MyDataSourceAttribute`.

EDIT 1:

Or, as an alternative, you derive from DataSource as above, but instead of building an absolute path and passing it onto the base constructor you simple pass all arguments unmodified. Then, in you constructor you would throw an exception if `connectionString` does not represent an absolute path. For example:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyDataSource : DataSource
{
    public MyDataSource(string providerInvariantName, string connectionString, string tableName, DataAccessMethod dataAccessMethod)
        : base(providerInvariantName, connectionString, tableName, dataAccessMethod)
    {
            if(!Path.IsRooted(connectionString))
                throw new ArgumentException("You have to pass an absolute path!");
    }
}
```

This way you will now get an exception if you attempt to use a non-absolute path. Note that using `Path.IsRooted` may not be the best way to test for an absolute path, but it's the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think the exception throwing is necessary in my case but good work around!